# OpenMP race condition while reading from pointer

Tags: c++, openmp

I know that reading from a shared variable in OpenMP does not cause a race condition, because every thread has it's own copy of that variable.
But if the shared variable is a pointer (e.g. to a container), then every thread only gets a copy of the pointer.

If I now read from the location the pointer is pointing to (my container), can there be race conditons or does OpenMP somehow take care of this?

Is it better to share a copy of the container itself, instead of a pointer to it, among threads?

Comment: OpenMP threads have own instance of _private_ variables, not _shared_. Any shared variable usage can cause a race if you don't use it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reading from a variable cannot produce a race condition: it doesn't matter whether the variable is shared or not. To produce a race condition you need to have two or more threads trying to modify the same instance of a variable at the same time.

Then, assuming that your threads are reading and modifying a certain variable, if you make this variable shared you will still have a race condition since all the threads share the same instance. I guess that in your first paragraph you wanted to say private, as @ilotXXI pointed out.

About your question about privatizing a pointer, if two o more instances of that pointer point to the same data and they modify it, you will have a race condition (each thread has a private version of the pointer but not a private version of the data).

Note that changing from one data-sharing clause to another may change the behavior of your application. Thus, in general, when you are parallelizing an application, what you have to do first is to analyze which kind of data accesses your application is performing. Once you know that, you have to think which data-sharing clauses and which synchronization constructs (if needed) you should use to keep the original behavior of your application.